# FullCalendar does not display times in the column schedules

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

Using the plugin FullCalendar in order to store events, the plugin is not displaying the time in the column schedules. Follow the link to JSBin:

https://jsbin.com/jemejiq/edit?html,css,js,output

Could anyone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is moment js library properly added? check developer console in your web browser

Comment: you should add code in your question as per [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Your `slotDuration` is conflicting with your `minTime` and `maxTime`, if you change `minTime` to `minTime: "05:00:00"` it will display. Or you can change your `slotLabelInterval` to `slotLabelInterval: "00:60:00"`, or `slotDuration` to `slotDuration: "00:60:00"`. The way it is currently they cannot go into the hours properly.